# Exclude Views field from displaying and just print it in field template?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a field (title) in my View that I want to print in another views field template, using:

```
print ($fields["title"]->content);
```

However, when I use the above code, the field now prints twice. So I tried to Exclude it from the display in Views, but then my above print stopped working. How can I exclude the field, but still print it somewhere else??

Thanks for the help

P.S. I am referring to Views fields, not Content Type fields.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Field prints twice, or not at all when added to template file](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/151305/field-prints-twice-or-not-at-all-when-added-to-template-file)

Comment: @Darvanen no, this is for Views, not Content Type displays :)

Comment: Ok, fair enough, what's the rest of the code in your field template file?

Comment: @Darvanen I want to include the title field in another view field template. So I have tried to print the title using the code above ^, but when I print I get double title, I just need the one, but when I set it to Exclude from display in Views neither shows up.

Comment: I have got a render content in the Views template, but when I remove it then all the fields disappear

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the field from display empties the `$field['name']->content`, so that when the renderer gets to the default field template, there's nothing to print.

If you absolutely cannot achieve your intended result using tokens and **Rewrite Output** then I suggest you:

- Do as you have already done to print the title in a different field's template
- Create a field template for title that is empty